# Wildfly 9 Load-Balancing

Tags: jboss, mod-cluster

I have two Wildfly 9 nodes running in standalone mode.

```
192.168.1.34 - node1 - Listening on 8080
192.168.1.35 - node2 - Listening on 8080

192.168.1.33 - myserver - Listening on 8080
```

I want to load-balance between the two nodes so that requests coming into myserver get split between the two nodes. I'm new to Wildfly but I see many references to built-in mod_cluster.

**What is the simplest way to load-balance between multiple JBoss nodes?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to use **Undertow** as a loadbalancer for **WildFly 9**. Undertow is a new web server in WildFly. The advantage is, you don't need to play with native components (Apache httpd for instance) and their (usually not so simple) configuration.

Read about the [loadbalancer configuration in WildFly documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Using+Wildfly+as+a+Load+Balancer).

Or just watch [following video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xa_gtRDpwyQ), where Stuart Douglas (Undertow developer) explains how it works and makes live demo.

Comment: The JBoss documentation leaves much to be desired. The video rocks, though. Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to set up load balancing cluster using Apache HTTPD 2.4.23 mod_cluster + JBoss EAP 7. I am cannot log in into my application. I am sharing my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454068/load-balancing-cluster-not-working-with-apache-http-server-2-4-6-and-jboss-eap-7